# listing values after search and index on excel providing no values

Tags: excel

Having some trouble on Excel. I am trying to create a search function that will return all the relevant info from column 's' on a separate worksheet, if the information on the same row in column 'bb' matches that of cell K10 on the main worksheet.

I get no errors with it, but whenever I enter a value in K10 no list appears.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Transactions!S$2:S$2000,SMALL(IF(Transactions!BB$2:BB$2000=K$10,ROW(Transactions!S$2:S$2000)-ROW(Transactions!S$2)+1),ROWS(M$11:M500))),"")
```

Comment: Change this `ROWS(M$11:M500)` to `ROW(1:1)` unless you want the 489th smallest row, which I suspect is more than the number of rows returned.

Comment: Thanks, it is now returning a value. What is this part of the function doing now if you don't mind me asking? Curious as to what my error was in terms of actual process

Comment: The second Criterion in Small is the instance,  `1` means the first, `2` the second smallest, `3` the third smallest... So with `ROWS(M$11:M500)` it returns a number, the number of rows in the reference `489` so you were looking for the 489th row that met the criteria.  `ROW(1:1)` returns 1.  When dragged down it will change to `2` then `3` and ...